# Argument of type RequestOptions is not assignable to to paramater of type {headers}

Tags: angular

I am upgrating my angular application to angular 7 and have a problem with my existing header implementation.

Existing method

```
private getPutHeaders() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
        , withCredentials: true
    });
}

getAllDocuments(strategyIds: Array<number>, documentTypeIds: Array<number>) {
        var payload = new AllDocumentsPayload()
        payload.DocumentTypeIds = documentTypeIds.join();
        payload.StrategyIds = strategyIds.join();
        return this.http.put(this.config.api.getAllDocuments, JSON.stringify(payload), this.getPutHeaders());
    }
```

I presmume we would need to use HttpHeaders instead of Headers in the getPutHeaders function but then I then I am not able to set the headers under request option as it doesnt recognise the headers.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `HttpClient.put` has no argument with type `RequestOptions`. Notice that type of `options` arguments is:

```
options?: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType?: 'json';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
```

which is not assignable to RequestOptions.

I am handling that by creating own interface `IRequestOptions` which is similar type as `options` argument. It's type-safe and works great.

Comment: Could you share me how the IRequestOptions looks like as I am not clear of its implementation and how it fixes the problem

Comment: I think RequestOptions is deprecated and need not use it